# I want to pass a index through navigate(`/login/${index}') and fetch it in another component in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I used `useNavigate()` to pass an index from one component and want to fetch it in another component.

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
const profileClick = (e, index) => {
  navigate(`/profile/${index}`);
}
```

Index is passed from here:

```
<button 
  onClick={e => {
    profileClick(e, data.id)
  }} 
  className="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
>
  Profile
</button>
```

I want to pass the variable to this component:

```
function Profile() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Profile</h1>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Just as an FYI, you can simplify your `onClick` event to be `onClick={() => profileClick(data.id)}`. And then declare your function like: `profileClick = index => { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are passing an index as through `useNavigate`, you must have one route registered as `profile/:index`, if not firstly register a route using `Route`.

Once you are done with registering route, you can use a hook providing by `react-router`, that is `useParams()`.

For example -

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom"; 

function Profile(){
    const params = useParam();
    return (<>
        <h1>Profile - {params?.index}</h1> // Here index will be same as the name you provided while registering the route.
    </>);
}
```

You can refer this docs, for reading more about how to read params - [link](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial#reading-url-params)